# How to calculate area of a path in a rectangle

Tags: geometry, solution-verification, area

I am stuck in a question. So, I have a garden with the below dimensions $23,8$ m and $16,7$ m.
If I will make a path as in the picture with width $6$m.
By how many percentage the area of the garden will be decreased?

My solution was calculating the area of garden so $23,8 \operatorname{m}\cdot 16,7\operatorname{m} = 397,46 \operatorname{m^2}$ then calculating the area of the path $6 \operatorname{m}\cdot 16,7\operatorname{m} = 100,2 \operatorname{m^2}$ and after I check the percentage of path comparing to the garden $100,2 \cdot 100 / 397,46 = 25,21 \%$

Can someone please confirm me if I am correct ?
Thank you for your support.

[image]

Comment: You are right, but note that $\dfrac{100.2}{394.12}\approx0.2542=25.42\%$. There is no need for multiplying by $100$, unless you drop the percent sign on the right side.

Comment: That's correct. Notice that the factor of $16.7$ canceled out, so the result is just $6/23.8$.

Comment: I corrected your calculations, you had copied the text wrong